# Use a local image in Pug 2.0.3

Tags: pug

I have the following folder structure:

```
-project  
  -images  
    -logo.png  
  -views  
    -layout.pug
```

In the layout.pug file I am trying to reference the image found at `project/images/logo.png` and my efforts to use a relative path have failed.

```css
img(src="project/images/logo.png" alt="Project Logo")
img(src="../images/logo.png" alt="Project Logo")
img(src="./images/logo.png" alt="Project Logo")
img(src="/images/logo.png" alt="Project Logo")
```

This is the first project where I am using pug, but I think I need to tell pug to require the image somehow, I just don't know how. How can I use a local image within a pug template? Is there any additional software required to do this?

Comment: What is your environment setup?

Comment: I am using Node and Express.

Comment: You need to make sure your image is being served by your server. Try browsing to the direct link of your image. Does it work?

Comment: so my server file is located in the project folder- when I browse to localhost:8080/images/logo.png I get a message stating "Cannot GET /images/logo.png" 
Is this a routing problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to serve up the static content using express. by putting the images folder into my public folder and serving up the public folder in express this solved my problem. 
Within the app.js file I added

```
express.use('public');
```